# Loop de números randomicos

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer um loop dos meus números randômicos.... Tenho dois spinner, 1 com escolha de quantos números randômicos e o outro quantas vezes tem que aparecer em uma ListView...

o meu problema é que ele gera a quantidade de números aleatórios, mas não a quantidade de vezes. Queria saber como fazer .... Pois não estou conseguindo

Código:

```
package com.nathan.lotogera.lotogera.Fragments;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nathan.lotogera.lotogera.Controller.MegaSenaController;
import com.nathan.lotogera.lotogera.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DuplaSena extends Fragment {

    private TextView groupText, quantJogos;
    private Button calculate;
    private SeekBar jogos;
    private ListView lista;
    private Spinner spinner, teste;

    String [] valuesRound =
            {"Quantidade de Nº","6", "7"};

    String [] multiplicar =
            {"Teste","1","2", "3"};

    public DuplaSena() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dupla_sena, container, false);

        groupText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listateste);
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerNumber);
        teste = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.teste);
        calculate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMostrar);

        groupText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesRound);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 1:
                        geraSix();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        geraSeven();
                        break;
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nenhum item selecionado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                groupText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, multiplicar);
        adapters.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        teste.setAdapter(adapters);

        teste.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position){
                    case 1:
                        int qant = teste.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        for(int a = 0; a>=qant; a++){
                            geraSix();
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        int qz = teste.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        for(int a = 1; a<=qz; a++){
                            geraSix();
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nenhum item selecionado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    public void geraSix(){
        List<String> teste = new ArrayList<>();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> listagem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                teste
        );

        lista.setAdapter(listagem);

        MegaSenaController numberRandom = new MegaSenaController();
        numberRandom.megaSena();
        String groupFirst = numberRandom.getPrimary();
        listagem.add(groupFirst);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o ArrayList `teste` tem que ficar fora do método `geraSix`, para ele não ser constantemente inicializado (e perder os valores anteriores), ou seja, seu método GeraSix apenas adiciona strings nesse ArrayList e não no adapter. Quando precisar zerar o ArrayList, faça no início do loop que chama os métodos GeraSix.

O adapter da ListView você pode inicializar logo no início da Activity, mesmo que vazio (e não constantemente no GeraSix). Quando o loop que chama os métodos GeraSix terminar, você simplesmente chama o método `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` que o spinner será atualizado.

Algo assim:

```
List<String> teste;
ArrayAdapter<String> listagem;

public View onCreateView(...) {
    ...
    teste = new ArrayList<>();
    listagem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                teste
    );

    lista.setAdapter(listagem);
    ...
}

public void geraSix(){
        MegaSenaController numberRandom = new MegaSenaController();
        numberRandom.megaSena();
        String groupFirst = numberRandom.getPrimary();
        teste.add(groupFirst);
    }


// No código que for rodar os GeraSix
teste.clear();
for(...){
   GeraSix();
}
listagem.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Boa noite, não consegui entender o que você quis dizer, se eu tiro o Arraylist como que o gerarSix vai adicionar no adapter? Isso que não entendi

Comment: Então, foi como eu falei, no GeraSix só precisa adicionar itens no ArrayList. Quando terminar de rodar todos os GeraSix necessários, chama o notifyDataSetChanged() do adapter que ele vai reler o ArrayList e atualizar o spinner, supondo que você já inicializar o adapter lá no OnCreate, como também sugeri.

Comment: Editei a resposta